# Indicator expected value

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$~$Uc(0,1)$

You flip a coin twice with probability $X$ to get "Heads".
Let $Y$ is the number of Heads you get .
Let $I$ be an Indicator that get the value 1 if $Y=2$ and $0$ otherwise.
What is the expected value of $I$?

I think  the answer is $X^2$ because the expected value of an indicator is just the probability to get the value 1.
However I'm unsure about the answer.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $X^2$ is the value of the **conditional** expectation of $I$ given $X$, that is, $\mathbb{E}[I \mid X]$. However, you are after $\mathbb{E}[I]$, which is different.

**Hint** to calculate this: use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[I] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]]$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

In essence, we have to account for the fact that the heads probability $X$ is random rather than fixed, so we can't just say the answer is $X^2$.

Comment: Isn't $E[I|X]=E[E[I|X]]$ and then $E[I]=E[I|X]=X^2$

Comment: This is not correct unfortunately. Why do you think that $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ equals $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]]$? (Note that by the law of total expectation, the latter equals the **unconditional** expectation $ \mathbb{E}[I]$. The former is the **conditional** expectation, which is a different thing.)

Comment: I thought so because $E[I|X]$ is a constant and the expectation of a constant is the constant .
I'm having a hard time to understand what $E[E[I|X]]$ means or how to calculate it.

Comment: I see. Well basically, when you take an expectation conditioned on a random variable like this, the conditional expectation **is itself a random variable**, not just constant. So, $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ **is a random variable**, and we can do usual things like compute its expectation etc. The expectation of $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ will thus be a constant, but $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ isn't  a constant (it's a random variable).

Comment: Oh ,
If i cant treat it as a random variable the answer should be $$\int_0^1 X E[I|X] \,dx=\int_0^1 x^3 \,dx=1/4$$ ?

Comment: Here is hopefully some intuition on why $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ is random. You can think of $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ as meaning "the expected value of $I$ given the value of $X$". However, such an expected value depends very much on what (random!) value $X$ takes! (E.g. if $X$ happened to take value $0.01$, this conditional expectation is very different to if $X$ took the value $0.99$.) In other words, $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]$ is random because it depends on (is a function of) the random variable $X$.

Comment: Actually, $\mathbb{E}[I\mid X] = X^2$ (a random variable), and $\mathbb{E}[I]= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[I\mid X]] = \mathbb{E}[X^2]$. So you end up just having to compute the expected value of $X^2$.

Comment: That does make sense . I appreciate the explanation .